# Expressing these sentences as conditional probability

Tags: probability

This question is a linguistic question a bit. I actually understand Bayes theorem from the mathematical point but I am always a bit confused when I encounter these kinds of sentences:

```
Person P is correct 70% of time. Person P says it will rain.
```

Now if I decide that:

```
R ... it will rain. 
A ... P says it will rain.
```

It is hard for me to make some intuitive reasoning whether to say:

```
P(A|R) = 0.7
```

or

```
P(R|A) = 0.7
```

It just seems to me that both statements express the situation. Can you give me some intuitive explanation why the second statement is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The first one says

"The probability P says it will rain GIVEN that it will rain is 0.7"

If it will rain, there's a 70% chance P will predict it. What's the chance that P predicts rain when it does rain? If it was 1, P would almost never incorrectly fail to predict rain that does occur. If it was 0, P would almost never predict the rain when it occurs.

The second one says

"The probability that it will rain GIVEN that P says it will rain is 0.7"

If P predicts it will rain, there's a 70% chance it will rain. If this one is near 1, if P says it will rain, it almost certainly will. If this is near 0, when P predicts rain, it almost certainly will not rain.

They are not quite the same, because the first one shows how unlikely it is for P to fail to make the prediction when he/she should, while the second one shows how unlikely it is for P to make a bad prediction.

In terms of the initial question, it could maybe use some more detail, but I think it means that 70% of P's affirmative predictions are correct (ignoring the failure to predict what does happen). Interpreted this way, I suspect we want P(R|A) = 0.7 -- if P predicts rain, 70% of the time it does rain -- 70% of P's predictions are correct.

Comment: I actually understand the meaning of the conditional probabilities written. I am just not so sure which one to pick when the sentence is as vague as "Person P is correct 70% of time" because they both seem quite reasonable. Might be that it is just ambiguous?

Comment: I see, see the last paragraph in the edited version - I suspect this is the intention of the question, but I see why it may seem ambiguous.

What it's doing is ignoring Type II errors (false negatives): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_I_and_type_II_errors#False_negative_error